# Codeigniter/HTTPS issues on Openshift

Tags: https, codeigniter-2, openshift

I am unable to even get CI's welcome page to come up on OpenShift - likely because of https. I checked my config file and it detects HTTPS and produces a correct base_url:

```
$config['base_url']="https//mysite.rhcloud.com/CI_base/";
```

But that seems to be as far as it goes - nothing in the response to CI's GET call. (I don't have a .htaccess set up. )

```
GET /CI_base/index.php
```

When I compare this to the GET request on my localhost system (over http), I noticed that the headers were a little different. But I can't tell which ones may be pointing to a culprit. The issue is probably jumping out at you - at least I hope so! Please could point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Mmiz

LOCALHOST HEADER:

```
**Connection**  Keep-Alive
**Content-Length**  1925
**Content-Type**    text/html
**Date**    Mon, 23 Sep 2013 17:16:17 GMT
**Keep-Alive timeout**=5, max=100
**Server**  Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8x
**Set-Cookie**  TW_COOK=Vj <more>; expires=Mon, 23-Sep-2013 19:16:18 GMT; path=/
**X-Powered-By**    PHP/5.3.15
```

OPENSHIFT HEADER

```
**Connection**  Keep-Alive
**Content-Encoding**    gzip
**Content-Length**  121
**Content-Type**    text/html
**Date**    Mon, 23 Sep 2013 17:16:55 GMT
**Keep-Alive**  timeout=15, max=100
**Server**  Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
**Vary**    Accept-Encoding
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default your application on Openshift responds to both http and https. For instance, if you use the following Codeigniter quickstart https://github.com/openshift/CodeIgniterQuickStart, you can go to `http://ci-$yournamespace.rhcloud.com` and `https://ci-$yournamespace.rhcloud.com`. To route to https by default take a look at this article here: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202398810-How-to-redirect-traffic-to-HTTPS-